# Load a heavy links txt to scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pycharm

i'm trying to load scrapy a text file over 900mb, but scrapy says "error memory". So I have to split the file into 2 parts to be able to load it to scrapy.

load links to scrapy:

```
links = [l.strip() for l in open(r"D:/linksd.txt").readlines()]
```

extract lines:

```
count= 0
for line in open('D:/linksd.txt'):
    count= count+ 1
    if count<2000000:
    f = open("D:/links-ext.txt", "a")
    f.write(line)
    f.close()
```

How can I load the links file directly to scrapy, without splitting it? I use pycharm and increase the "maximum heap size", but no results.

Comment: Iterate over file lines in `start_requests` so that you do not need to load the whole file in memory.

Comment: that's what I'm looking for but I can't do it

Comment: “I can't do it” does not tell me much. Could you elaborate? What’s preventing you from doing it?

Comment: I tried to use loop line reads, but on first read the Scrapy ends

Comment: Is the file itself the issue? It’s possible you simply cannot have that may requests in memory at once. Does [JOBDIR](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html) make any difference?